# Why did Nietzsche say he would not live his life again?

Tags: nietzsche, nihilism, art, merleau-ponty

Why did Nietzsche say he would not live his life again?

Kaufman Gay Science  p. 19 introduction...

> “Nietzsche in ... one of his
>   notes...  “I do not want life again. How did I endure it? Creating.
>   What makes me stand the sight of it? The vision of the overman who
>   affirms life. I have tried to affirm it myself / alas”. “

Was he not his overman, because surely he was? Has anyone linked that to his madness, and perhaps [Cezanne's doubt?](https://www.scribd.com/doc/109323131/Merleau-Ponty-Cezanne-s-Doubt) As Cezanne, if not Artaud, is probably the best example of a madman who retained his genius, and was I think only able to paint sometimes.

Comment: A reference would help provide some specificity and context here -- also some grounding or unpacking of the Cezanne/Artaud connection you're inquiring about might be helpful if you are hoping for a response specifically to that line of thinking

Comment: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~pj97/Nietzsche.htm, Nietzsche did not consider himself an overman.

Comment: damnit i'll ask for the citation but delete for now @JosephWeissman

Comment: @Robus "Nietzsche might or might not consider himself an overman" ?

Comment: What is "Cezanne's doubt" ? What is the link with Merleau-Ponty's interpretation of some painting of [Paul Cézanne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_C%C3%A9zanne) with Nietzsche' Hubermensch ?

Comment: cezanne's doubt is the title of what i linked to isn't it @MauroALLEGRANZA sorry i don't understand why you're objecting to this. do i need to summarize the paper beyond what i end the question with? i'd have to reread it

Comment: https://www.age-of-the-sage.org/philosophy/nietzsche_philosophy.html, .....“although he explicitly denied that any Superman or overman had yet arisen”.....among other quotes here. Sorry if my previous link was deficient.

Comment: sounds ambiguous @Robus

Comment: Throughout TGS he also complains continually about how hard his health and the stupidity of the world is on him, and he fact that he cannot quite manage it.

Comment: @jobermark hahaha

Comment: Life just isn't that great if you think about it deeply. In fact it's tedious. You can breeze through it with joy if you don't look it in the eyes. But to a person that values intelligence.. ignorance isn't an option. It really doesn't take more than one lifetime to see the absolute futility of it. Yes there are moments of joy.. but they're not so great you'd come back and do it again.. just for that smile... Those ten minutes with that girl. That one goal. Been there... Bought the T-Shirt.

Comment: Is it possible the overman is artificial intelligence? And ‘thus’ he could not be an overman. @confused